# I was working while I was studying at college

Tags: past-tense, past-continuous

I was working while I was studying at college, is it correct?

And how to tell about past actions for example:

'In college I had a subject 'Web design' where I was making a static web-page', is it correct?

Comment: Idiomatically we wouldn't usually use continuous verb forms for no good reason, so it's *I **worked** while I **studied** at college* and *I **made** a static web-page*. But grammatically your versions are fine. Note that for the first example, even if I specifically wanted to call attention to "the passage of time", I'd probably only do this with ***one*** of the verb forms *working* or *studying*, depending on which activity I wanted to focus on (doing it for *both* makes for a verbose / clumsy construction).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica , I am studying right now, but don't work and i want to report about my work experience, especially about time management. For example (Time management was the biggest challenge i faced during my study at college. Because i was studying at college while i was working at X job. And sometimes i skipped my lessons because i had to go to work